# How to add multiple eventhandlers efficiently

Tags: java, javafx

i want to have a grid 18*18 of buttons, if clicked they should return their position on the grid, in order to check the condition of said square.
i tried using for looped but

```
package application;

import code.Field;
import code.Square;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class ControllerClass {

    @FXML
    private VBox vbox;
    private HBox [] hbox;
    private Button [][] button;
    
    private Square selectedSquare;
    private Field field;
    @FXML
    public void initField() {
        
        hbox=new HBox[18];
        button=new Button[18][18];
        for(int i=0;i<18;i++) {
            hbox[i]=new HBox();
            hbox[i].setPrefHeight(60);
            vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox[i]);
            for(int j=0;j<18;j++) {
                button[i][j]=new Button(i+";"+j);
                button[i][j].setPrefSize(60, 60);
                button[i][j].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        selectedSquare=field.getSquare(i, j);
                    }
                });
                hbox[i].getChildren().add(button[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

but the eventhandler obviously cant know the value of i and j.
so how can i do this without typing 324 eventhandlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler can know the value of `i` and `j`: you just have to copy them to final variables:

```
public void initField() {
    
    hbox=new HBox[18];
    button=new Button[18][18];
    for(int i=0;i<18;i++) {
        hbox[i]=new HBox();
        hbox[i].setPrefHeight(60);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<18;j++) {
            button[i][j]=new Button(i+";"+j);
            button[i][j].setPrefSize(60, 60);
            final int row = i ;
            final int column = j ;
            button[i][j].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    selectedSquare=field.getSquare(row, column);
                }
            });
            hbox[i].getChildren().add(button[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it's probably a bit more elegant just to define a method for creating and configuring the button:

```
public void initField() {
    
    hbox=new HBox[18];
    button=new Button[18][18];
    for(int i=0;i<18;i++) {
        hbox[i]=new HBox();
        hbox[i].setPrefHeight(60);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<18;j++) {
            button[i][j]=createButton(i, j);
            hbox[i].getChildren().add(button[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

private Button createButton(int i, int j) {
    Button button = new Button(i+";"+j);
    button.setPrefSize(60, 60);
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            selectedSquare=field.getSquare(i, j);
        }
    });
    return button ;
}
```

(The latter version works because the *local* variables `i` and `j` in the `createButton()` method are never changed after they are initialized. Hence they are "effectively final" and so can be captured by lambda expressions and anonymous inner classes.)

Note that it's fairly likely here you don't actually need to keep the array of buttons: just create them and set up their handlers, and add them to the scene graph:

```
public void initField() {
    
    hbox=new HBox[18];
    for(int i=0;i<18;i++) {
        hbox[i]=new HBox();
        hbox[i].setPrefHeight(60);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<18;j++) {
            hbox[i].getChildren().add(createButton(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These are both not elegant, as it suffices to get an identifier on click.

Comment: @MartinZeitler What identifier though? To do that, you need to specifically create an identifier for each button, which is not needed in this solution.